# Commutativity of $\bigcup$ and $\wp$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In his *Naive Set Theory*, Halmos in Section 5, *Complements and Powers*, asks the following.

> Show that $E$ is always equal to $\bigcup_{X\in\wp (E)} X$ (that is $E=\bigcup\wp (E)$), but that the result of applying $\wp$ and $\bigcup$ to $E$ in the other order is a set that includes $E$ as a subset, typically a proper subset.

I’ve been able to show the first part. For the second part, I don’t think that $E$ can be a subset of $\wp\bigl(\bigcup E\bigr)$.

---

$\wp (X)$ means power set of $X$.

Comment: Are you using the Weierstrass symbol to mean power-set?

Comment: Yes, yes.......

Comment: Note that this works under the convention (standard in set theory) that everything is a set, and so extensionality holds absolutely. Otherwise, performing these operation in the opposite order might be nonsensical.

Comment: Didn't we say something about descriptive titles?

Comment: @AsafKaragila okay now?

Comment: Slightly better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y\in\bigcup E$ if and only if there is some $x\in E$ such that $y\in x$. Therefore any $x\in E$ is equal to $\left\{y\in \bigcup E\,:\, y\in x\right\}$. In other words, every element of $E$ is indeed a subset of $\bigcup E$.

Answer (score 2):

A simple illustration of the second fact: let $E=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, then $\bigcup E = \{\emptyset\}$ (all elements of elements of $E$ together) and $\mathscr{P}\left(\bigcup E)\right) = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ which indeed properly contains $E$ as a subset.

That $E \subseteq \mathscr{P}(\bigcup E)$ is clear:

suppose that $x \in E$. Then $x \subseteq \bigcup E$ (because every $y \in x$ will be in the union $\bigcup E$ by definition) and so $x \in \mathscr{P}\left(\bigcup E\right)$ (a subset of the union is an element of the powerset of the union).

As Henning Makholm pointed out, iff $E$ is a powerset of some set, we will have $E= \mathscr{P}\left(\bigcup E\right)$.

Comment: $E = \mathcal P(\bigcup E)$ holds if and only if $E$ is a power set of _something_. ("Only if" is trivial; "if" follows from $\bigcup\mathcal P(X)=X$). Transitivity doesn't enter into it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I tried the ordinal $2$ first but saw it was not an example. So I thought transitivity was the reason...